# Facing issue while using Module Map to expose objective c header files in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, sdk, frameworks

**I am working on iOS SDK, In my project I have both objective c and swift files. So for this I have created a framework, in this I have used module map to expose objective C header files to Swift by importing that module map to swift files.**

POC

```
module MyModuleMap{
header “Calculate.h”
export *
}
```

//importing modulemap in swift

```
import MyModuleMap
@objcMembers
Public class Simplify : NSObject {
Public var cal : Calculate?
Public var name : String?
}
```

Now, what is happening In my actual project in Objective-C generated interface header (just for ex :MyProject-swift.h) this module map got imported (@import MyProjectModuleMap;) like this and error is coming module ‘MyModuleMap’ not found, but in my POC this issue is not coming and also in Objective-C generated interface header(ex: MyPOC-swift.h) module map(@import  MyModuleMap)is not imported.

So, I am not able to figure out why this is happening in my actual project and not in my POC.
Please guide me if anyone have any idea regarding this issue, how I can get rid of this error.

Thanks

In my actual project in Objective-C generated interface header (just for ex :MyProject-swift.h) this module map got imported (@import MyProjectModuleMap;) like this and error is coming module ‘MyModuleMap’ not found, but in my POC this issue is not coming and also in Objective-C generated interface header(ex: MyPOC-swift.h) module map(@import  MyModuleMap)is not imported.